# 2 times 'that' in sentence confuses me to understand the meaning

Tags: grammar, meaning

2 times 'that' in sentence confuses me to understand the meaning.
Could you also explain how to divide grammatical parts?

> But they cannot get to **that** deep stomach fat **that** abdominal etching
>   removes.

VOA article - Forget Exercising: Surgeons Can Make the Stomach Look Muscular

Comment: *But they cannot get to the deep stomach fat removed by abdominal etching.* (I suspect the first use of *that* only makes sense in the context of a previous sentence.)

Comment: The first *that* is used as a demonstrative pronoun, the second is used as a conjunction. I'd recommend you do a little exploring to find out what those terms mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first "that" is a demonstrative: "*that* deep stomach fat" is a noun phrase, like "*this* deep stomach fat".

The second "that" is a relative pronoun: "fat *that* abdominal etching removes", like "fat *which* abdominal etching removes".

They're also pronounced differently: in my dialect, the first one is /ðæt/ and the second is /ðət/.

The whole sentence could be written without "that" and without changing the meaning much: "But they cannot get to *the* deep stomach fat *which* abdominal etching removes."